# how to generate amount of array elements from value in textbox

Tags: php

I have text box:
Size of array: 
After this i have button Show array:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <form name="form" method="post">
            Size of array: <input type="number"value="5" name="size", min="2", max="10">
    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Show array"></span></p> 
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['Send']))
            {
            //what must be here?
            }
    ?>
```

but i don't know, how to generate random numbers from digits, which is entered in text box, e.g. if text box contains 8, then generates 8 random numbers from 2 until 10..can u help please ?

Comment: for a start your form has no input to add the number to be posted

Comment: @IdontDownVote will be better now ?

Comment: great but the input needs a `name` value as well then  i guess `rand()`, but im not sure what "8 random numbers from 2 until 10" do you want "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" in a random order? or 8 numbers between 2-10 allowing duplicates?

Comment: @IdontDownVote cannot duplicates. It can also to be 2,8,4,5,3,6,7,9
if i entered 4, then it generates 4 random numbers from 2 to 10 (5,3,7,6)
`$numb = range(size);` i have this one string of code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit new version i think is what you want??

```
 $numb=range(2,10); 
 shuffle($numb);
 $output = array_slice($numb, 0, $_POST['guess']);

 echo implode(',',$output);
```

`range()` to make an array of the numbers you want to use (2-10). `shuffle` randomises them,  `array_slice()` picks the number of elements according to the form input. `implode` for display.

Old version:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <form name="form" method="post">
            Size of array: <input name="guess" type="number" value="5" name="size", min="2", max="10">
    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Show array"></span></p> 
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Send']))
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['guess']; $i ++) {
        $random[] = rand(2, 10);
    }
    echo implode(',', $random);
}
?>
```

the `for` loop is running the number of times the user selected, and the `rand` is picking the numbers, `implode` is gluing the numbers together for output

Comment: right now cant check, because host does not load, idk why! when it will be available, i will check your answer! :-)

Comment: what if i need use var_dump ?

Comment: then use it? `var_dump($output);` ?

Comment: i need output format `int(4) int(7) int(6) int(2)`

Comment: all ok...........